# Change default Docker temp directory to host temp directory

Tags: docker, webpack, nodes

I'm running a Webpack dev task in a Docker container. Webpack caches output files in the system's default temp directory. Node's default temp directory on the host system (OSX) is a subdirectory of `/var/folders`. Node's default temp directory in the container is `/usr/src/app`. Webpack running in the Docker container is caching files in the project directory. I'd rather not set this directory explicitly in the Webpack config. Instead, I'd like to configure the container's default temp directory to be the host temp directory, whatever that might be. Is there an option to do this?

Answer (score 0):

The container has no access to the host filesystem unless you mount it.
So you'd have to share the folder you want to use from the host to the container and mount it where the container expects to use it

Comment: If I pass the path to the host system tmpdir when calling `docker run`, webpack running in the container is able to write to that directory. So that's what I'm doing.